# How can I perform a join using a concatenated field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I would like to know how to approach performing a join using a concatenated field.

I have one table `Task` that has a value `User`.  I want to join the `Users` table which has the value `Logon` the inner join works fine now (listed below).

I want to concatenate the field `User` and the field `EMP_Num` from the `Users` table to get a unique value something like *ASmith1234*, instead of *Asmith* which is more generic (current value).

**After I do the concatenation, how do I join this field?**

```sql
JOIN [Users] [USE] 
 ON [Task].[User] = [USE].[Logon]
```

**What is a good approach to solving this?**

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join with a concatenated field in this way:

```sql
SELECT *  
 FROM demo a
  INNER JOIN demo b
   ON a.name+cast(a.id as varchar) = b.name+cast(b.id as varchar)
```

You can run this code [here](https://sqliteonline.com/).

**But I didn't suggest you do this!**

Based on this [article](https://blog.jooq.org/dont-use-the-string-concatenation-trick-in-sql-predicates/), you should join through your two fields separately.
In your database somehow this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM Users U
  JOIN Logon L
   ON U.User = L.User
   AND U.EMP_Num = L.EMP_Num
```

...If you really want to concatenate your fields and join through this, then in SQLServer you can use a [computed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) field for this...